# Slider toggle without CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm relatively proud of this toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/AmrnK/

The problem is that it is not cross-browser because it uses CSS transitions.

Any suggestions to build something similar using jQuery instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jQuery UI's `.switchClass()` for animation and jQuery's `.queue()` to change text at the end of the animation to reproduce this behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/william/AmrnK/2/

You could also use jQuery's `.animate()` if you don't want to have CSS classes.

Comment: Thanks great! Do you think you could make the button draggable within the container to make it even more usable?

Comment: That could probably be achieved with draggable and droppable: e.g. http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to...

Comment: Thanks! You have been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the fiddle you provided `CSS3` is only used to give a curved border and the shadow to html elements which is not possible using jQuery. You can use images to get such look and feel only if required.

In the fiddle the toggle was working only if you click on On/Off which is not a good UX. I have modified it to be effective throughout the toggle area take a look at this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/AmrnK/1/

Comment: Thanks. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions#AutoCompatibilityTable CSS transitions are experimental. Is there a more cross-browser alternative?